# How to do a for each for the rows in a datasets table?

Tags: vb.net, foreach

Hi I am trying to loop though the rows in a table of my dataset.

I am a C# developer and have been given a VB project so i am struggling with the For each below.

Could someone please tell me what is wrong with the line of code below?

```
 For Each Row as DataRow in dataset.Tables[0].Rows
    Do stuff//
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
Next
```

Comment: we use () in VB and [] in c#

Comment: For Each dr As datarow In ds.tables(0).rows
 Dim str1 As String = dr(0).tostring()
Next

Comment: use this site to convert c# code to Vb, if you are more familiar with c# http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Is it not dr.Item(0).ToString() ? But thanks i will mark as correct when the timer allows me too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
For Each drow As datarow In dataset.tables(0).rows
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can convert your C# code to VB.NET using below URL . This could help you

```
http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/
```

Thanks